# *Android Realm* After many queries, the insert will be slow

Tags: android, canvas, realm

I'm developing a drawing app for Android. paths are tracked and stored using the Realm. However, when I paint something on a canvas, it becomes exponentially slow. 
Through a variety of tests, I noticed that this case was occurring in a particular situation. When the user uses the Undo function several times, multiple queries are requested simultaneously. After doing so, I can see that the app is very slow to draw the pen on Canvas (insert data into Realm). What's really strange is that if the query is requested from another table, the speed will return to normal.

And I checked it's not something that's happening in the Canvas. (all codes has been removed in Canvas)
I've checked that it's going to slow down after I've just request SELECT queries.

```
public void executeUndo(int id, int noteId) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmResults<SomeTable1> packets = realm.where(SomeTable1.class)
            .beginGroup()
            .equalTo("command", "SomeCommand1")
                .or()
            .equalTo("command", "SomeCommand2")
                .or()
            .equalTo("command", "SomeCommand3")
                .or()
            .equalTo("command", "SomeCommand4")
            .endGroup()
            .equalTo("noteId", noteId)
            .findAllSorted("id", Sort.DESCENDING);

    // ... Some codes (codes are commented)

    realm.close();
}
```

Here are the code that stores the objects into realm

```
mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        while (true) {
            if (!Queue.getInstance().realmObjects.isEmpty()) {
                realm.beginTransaction();
                realm.copyToRealm(Queue.getInstance().realmObjects.pop());
                realm.commitTransaction();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd assume it's because you use many many transactions.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thank you! I put the data in a buffer and insert with it at once.

Comment: Did it help? I think it should :)